# HTML entity name for Backward slash

Tags: html, character, html-entities

What is the HTML entity name for Backward slash (`\`)?

For example:

`&lt;` represents **Lesser than**

`&gt;` represents **Greater than**

Similarly for other characters also. Is there any documentations regarding this?

Comment: '/' is not a backslash. It is a (forward) slash. Backslash ('\') in HTML is represented by &#92; & (forward) slash ('/') by &#47;

Comment: Sorry Updated. That was a typo error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`&bsol;` represents [**reverse solidus (backward solidus)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

(from this resource: http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

Comment: interesting: Although `&bsol;` and `&Backslash;` look the same at http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref: If you double-click both characters in the table, copy and paste them to an editor, only `&bsol;` will have the ASCII code 0x5C (note: UltraEdit pastes both as `5C`). **`&Backslash;` is in fact `&setminus;`** (U+2216), which is encoded (if I enunciate this correct) on my Windows with hex `E2 88 96`.

Answer (score 11):

Did you try :

```
Slash     : /  : &#47; : &sol;
Backslash : \  : &#92; : &bsol;
```

Answer (score 3):

Some browsers display the Japanese currency symbol Yen **¥** instead of backslash **\**, when Japanese or Korean font have been installed. 
See also Michael Kaplan's blog http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/09/17/469941.html

I was looking for HTML entity to replace the backslash characters in file pathes displayed on my webpages. Unfortunately, my Chrome displays both entities &#92; \ and &bsol; \ as Yen characters. 
But I found a very similar glyph on http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2980-29FF of Unicode character U+29F5 which renders as desired: **&#x29F5; ⧵**

Answer (score 1):

The backlash (\) can be used in HTML using two methods. These are;

1. `&#92;` and
2. `&bsol;`
   Note that the semi-colon (;) has to be included else it will not work.

Answer (score -1):

the entity name for backward slash(/) is :-  `&#47`;

Comment: That is the forward slash.  See @Val Bonn's answer.